# Округлить целое число до десятков

Tags: c#, округление

Допустим есть число

```
3686,55
```

Я хочу отбросить дробную часть - с этим можно справиться с помощью

```
Convert.ToInt32();
```

Теперь остается число 3686. Надо его округлять в зависимости от значения последней цифры - если оно в пределах `01234` - то округлять в меньшую сторону, а если `56789` - то в большую. В моем случае должно получиться 3690.

Я нашел методы для дробных чисел - но для целочисленных не смог найти. Подскажите как быть

Comment: *Я нашел методы для дробных чисел - но для целочисленных не смог найти.* Подели на нужную степень десятки, округли полученное "дробное", потом домножь обратно.

Answer (score 8):

Делите на 10, округляете как вещественное, приводите к целому, потом умножаете обратно на 10:

```
double d = 3686.55;

int i = (int) Math.Round(d / 10) * 10;

Console.WriteLine( i );
```

> ```
> 3690
> ```